# Stack Overflow Survey: Where do the developers go?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

Looking through the results of the Stack Overflow survey each year, one graph always interests me.

[image: Developers - time in profession]

Does this mean that people are flooding into coding, or is there a 'life-span' to coding, to which most of us will succomb?

If it's leaving, I found this [article](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-reasons-programmers-quit-their-high-paying-jobs), but it's just one person. Hardly representitive.

If they leave:

- Why (without wishing to invoke facetious answers)?
- Where do they go?
- Is this drop off rate normal?

(Incidentally, I've been coding 10+ years professionally, and can't imagine not coding, probably hence this question).

Comment: Well when I started 46 years ago there simply weren't many programming jobs.

Comment: @greg-449 The 20-25y range should look "fatter", though.

Comment: Well, speaking as a card-carrying member of the "Curmudgeon League", I'd say that they are still writing software -- they just used up all of their patience, so they don't hang around Stack Overflow anymore.

Comment: Most people after spending  8-10 on coding, move to other areas of the profession, like software architectural designing, code reviewing, etc

Comment: After 10-15 years of experience (depending on your country/ location) I don't think you'll still be writing code.

Comment: People do get fed-up doing the same thing for 7 years.  Filling out surveys is surely on the top of that list.  Being married to the same person might be next.

Comment: @Melchia Depending on personal preference, too. I still love writing code, for 18 years and counting.

Comment: @ModusTollens and you're one of the rare people who do :) But most of the people I've seen move to other aspects of software engineering like consulting & software architectural designing ...

Comment: I would actually expect this to be a problem with Stack Overflow: That they cannot keep *more* experienced developers around. The majority is obviously from the learners group but we have a problem attracting experts.

Comment: Is this not a off-topic question?

Comment: This question reminds me of Tyrion Lannister pondering on his father's rhetorical question "Where do whores go?"

Comment: This talk by "Uncle Bob" is relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHnLmvDxGTY&feature=youtu.be&t=792

Comment: There are a lot of anecdotal answers, but not solid data.  I'd love to see a future exdeveloper survey (perhaps a one-shot) separate from the regular developer survey.  However, getting responses might be trouble from escapees.  But I'd like to learn what percentage of people reason for the various whys. Are there certain technologies correlated with more attrition?  Are there pattens to what do escapees go on to do?  Knowing why others left would help us identify pitfalls to avoid and problems that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most industry measures indicate that a low percentage of developers leave altogether, although there are [troubling systemic exceptions](https://www.quora.com/Do-women-in-Silicon-Valley-experience-bias-in-the-workplace-in-2017-If-so-how).

Much more prominent is the continuing influx of new developers. Imagine that the number of professional developers in the world doubles every 5 years. That would mean that at any time, half of all software developers have less than 5 years of experience.

Comment: That would explain the survey results.  Can you cite any evidence to back it up?

Answer (score 10):

While I am only 21 and am from the "0-2 years" category, I've been coding for about 5 years and at some point came across [this questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) from meta.

> How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?
>
> asking a question on Stack Overflow is the absolute last thing you ever want to do. You want to avoid it at all costs.

And ever since then, I haven't asked a single question, and quite honestly, I'm a little ashamed of the questions I *have* asked. I've earned over 2/3 of my reputation (which isn't much at all) in the past 3 days answering questions that I can only describe as low-effort questions. In my actual coding experience, every question I've ever needed SO for has already been answered in one capacity or another.

And to that end, the older developers have probably realized that as well, or are experienced enough to read the manual. The few left are probably the moderators and other community volunteers.

Answer (score 2):

There may be many reasons.

1. Some are moving to other jobs like project managers, lectures, etc.
2. Some (they may used very active on Stack Overflow in past years and they may submitted past survey) are use Stack Overflow only when they need a help. This happen because of busy of life (financial problems, family issues, responsibility of job, etc.). So they may have not at least seen the Survey.
3. Some (in past years they may submitted past survey) are may active on Stack Overflow, but they may think that it is not worth to waste too much time to fill the survery. It is happens also because of their busy life.
4. It may boring to fill the long survey. Most young/new developers fill this survey for 1st, 2nd time.... But old ones are know Stack Overflow from long time and they may have filled this multiple times... So they don't have the curiosity to fill this.